# Vintage MTB with Hollowtech II - FD doesn't reach outer ring

Tags: commuter, vintage, 26-inch, miyata

I'm using a vintage Miyata Sports runner as my backup + winter bike. Mostly for commuting (2 x 11 km/day). The original square tapered crankset finally gave up beyond fixing last week and I got a new replacement ***FC-MT210-3*** + a ***MTB BB-MT800-K Bottom Bracket Hollowtech II*** from my neighbour.

- BB shell is 68mm wide
- My FD is: [Sora 3x9](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/sora-r3000/FD-R3030-B.html)
- My shifters are: Shimano XT ST-M750

I upgraded the bike with 3x9 drivetrain 2 years ago with a 3x Sora FD. It has been working perfectly fine.

I installed the new BB with the spacers according to the user guide (1 on drive side, 2 on non drive side) and installed the crankset. All fine.

The one problem I'm having is that I cannot get the FD to reach the outermost cogs.

Any ideas for how to solve it? Can I use fewer spacers? Or is the Sora FD not compatible with MTB cranksets? Or have I missed something else?

Thanks a million!

[image: Miyata Sports Runner ~1990]

Comment: The K version of the BB means it has altered spacing to accommodate a chain case bracket. I'm not sure exactly how it is different from a standard non-K version though. It may shift the chainline out a bit.

Comment: Can you confirm the model of your FD, the model of your shifters and the width of your bottom bracket shell?

Comment: @Armand Thanks! I had never heard of that there were a special BB for chainguards. Strangely I cannot find any information on it? Or what differs from the models without the -K?

Comment: @olliebulle I cannot se any model description on the FD but I think it's this one: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/sora-r3000/FD-R3030-B.html

Comment: @olliebulle My shifters are Shimano XT ST-M750

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main things I see:

1. You are using an MTB shifter with a road front derailleur. The cable pull ratio is different making them incompatible.
2. The chaineline is off. Your FC-MT210-3 has a 50 mm chaineline while your front derailleur has 45 mm.

A good way to check for compatible components is the compatibily charts on [si.shimano.com](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?q=FC-MT210-3&cid=C-432&acid=C-445). If we take your crankset has a starting point, we get the following:

[image]

The first column lists the compatible derailleurs which varies also according to your FC-MT210-3 chainrings configuration.